# How to parse this data type?

Tags: python

```
34216042-92b3-4245-bec1-312e886a80ab
 === Element (ent: sample) === 
 id                  : 123456
 name                : None
 accession_number    : L999999
 lab_date            : None
```

I have the following output from a database many times over.  How can I parse it so that I extract only the long number at the top and the accession number:
ie for each record print only:

```
34216042-92b3-4245-bec1-312e886a80ab
L999999
```

Comment: Is the number at the *top* going to have the same format?

Comment: Is the first, long, hex number a UUID?

Comment: yes the top hex number is a UUID

Comment: I have written this programme through a python api which is working nicely but I have no ideal how to parse this..

Comment: I suppose the accession number is a genome sequence, and not for a (book) library.

Comment: I don't understand where you're having trouble with this.  You grab input in 6-line chunks.  Save the entire first line.  Save the 3rd field of the 4th line.  Repeat for each data record.  What other semantics do you need?

Answer (score 0):

The first number is probably a UUID. Here is the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html).

Here is a small Python sample.

```
import uuid
x=uuid.UUID('34216042-92b3-4245-bec1-312e886a80ab')
print x # prints 34216042-92b3-4245-bec1-312e886a80ab
```

Comment: thanks I know it is a UUID but actually I just want to print it along with the accession number, I don't want to interpret the uuid

Comment: For parsing the accession number, please take a look at the (online) Biopython Tutorial and Cookbook: http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html.

Comment: The user is trying the extract that number from a string !